# Numbering of image saved from app resource to SD card

Tags: android, android-gallery, save-image

I have app consist of days listview each day has its specific images placed in an infinite gallery class , what im trying to do is:

**saving images with sequential number from app drawable resource ( infinite gallery class)  to sd card**,

im trying to get the sequential number of saved images as below :

first image :Image-1.png .

second image :Image-2.png .

third image : Image-3.png ,

and so on for all dayes .

with using :

```
 Random generator = new Random();
```

**This will lead to :**

**first issue** : saved images with random numbers .

**second issue** : its not saving all images was choose by user to save to sd card also it save some of  image twice or three times .

**This is the part of code which related to saving images :**

```
 View vi=convertView; 
    final ViewHolder holder; 
    if(convertView==null){ 
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_items, null); 
        holder=new ViewHolder(); 
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image); 
        holder.button=(Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.button_save);

 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mContext.getResources(), images[itemPos]);
         holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View arg0) {

      String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File imagesFolder = new File(root + "/Days pictures");    
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 1000;
     n = generator.nextInt(n);
     String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
     File file = new File (imagesFolder, fname);
     if (file.exists ())
       file.delete (); 
     try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}   
        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();    
       Toast.makeText(mContext, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}});

      vi.setTag(holder);}

    else holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag(); 
    holder.text.setText(name[itemPos]); 

    final int stub_id=images[itemPos]; 
    holder.image.setImageResource(stub_id); 

    return vi; } 

private ImageView getImageView() { 

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext); 

    return i; } }
```

thanks for your help .

Comment: If you want images in sequential order why are you generating Random Numbers..?

Comment: @Pragnani please tell me how is thr right way im new to android , thanks

Comment: Take n as a field and increment n everytime when you save the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and comments i can understand that you want to save n number of images to SDCard.

To save follow the steps

**STEP 1**: Get All the Images you need. Make sure you getting the list of images correctly here.

**STEP 2**: Count number of images in the list and store it in variale

```
      int numberOfImages = 15;// Get it dynamically
```

**STEP 3**: Now loop it to store all the images in sequential order

```
   //Create Directory to store images in SDCard
   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
       if(!myDir.exists()){
           myDir.mkdirs();
          } 
           // You have to get next image here from the resource here
           bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( mContext.getResources(), images[i]);// value for itemPos should be given here.

           // Get Last Saved Number
           SharedPreferences savedNumber = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
           int lastSavedNumber = savedNumber.getInt("lastsavednumber",0); 
           lastSavedNumber++;
           String fname = "Image-"+lastSavedNumber+".png";

           File file = new File (myDir, fname);
           if (file.exists ()) {file.delete (); }
           try {
                  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);//Your Bitmap from the resouce
                  out.flush();
                  out.close();

               } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }

      //To Store the last Number
     SharedPreferences saveNumber = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editorset = saveNumber.edit();
     editorset.putInt("lastsavednumber",lastSavedNumber);   
     editorset.commit();
```

The duplication can take place if you do any thing wrong in your first step.

**EDIT**
To Store All Images in Sequential Order Use SharedPreferences to Store last saved image number.

```
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "ImageNumber";  

    // Get Last Saved Number
    SharedPreferences savedNumber = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    int lastSavedNumber = savedNumber.getInt("lastsavednumber",0); 
    lastSavedNumber++;
    String fname = "Image-"+lastSavedNumber+".png";

    //To Store Last Saved Number
     SharedPreferences saveNumber = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editorset = saveNumber.edit();
     editorset.putInt("lastsavednumber",lastSavedNumber);   
     editorset.commit();
```

Comment: my dear friend im still new to development but what you mean by : // value for itemPos should be given here.
in your answer , im try to solve my problem then i will update my post to check it , thanks

Comment: I want to ask one question. From where you getting the image? and how you getting that image?. Can you update the code

Comment: i will update now the whole activity in my post which include the for loop fo save images to be more clear my friend ,thanks

Comment: Yes from the above code i can find that you will store only one image for number of times right. What you want to do now is `for example` if you want to store all the images in `Day1` then you need to get all the resources and assign to bitmap to store it in sdcard using loop

Comment: to clear my self , imagine you are user exploring my application , you open Day1 gallery you like 2 images from Day1 and want to save it to sd , then opend Day2 you dont like any images from its gallery , then open Day3 you like 3 images in Day3 gallery and want to save it and so on , so you can finally liable to save any images you choose either 1 image or 9 images or all images one by one , this is my idea but i dont want to save whole day images in one step , this is how i want it to work , thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28246/discussion-between-vino-and-androidqq6)

Comment: it save first imge oressed to save to sd card under name of Image-1.png , when you press second image to save it , it replace the first one , finally i have one image only in sd card folder

Comment: yes it will save only one image. its a first step you have to do some other stuff as well

Comment: edited the answer. It will store all images in sequential order. check it

Comment: Hi my friend does i need to repeate this piece of code twice : //To Store the last Number
     SharedPreferences saveNumber = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
     SharedPreferences.Editor editorset = saveNumber.edit();
     editorset.putInt("lastsavednumber",lastSavedNumber);   
     editorset.commit();

Comment: no you can see the difference between two. In first one you getting the image number. In Second peace of code you storing the incremented number

Comment: If you happy with my answer. then accept it as an answer. Happy coding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28375/discussion-between-vino-and-androidqq6)

Comment: would you please check this related new post to this question, thanks :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122799/save-clear-and-save-sharedpreferences-again

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `for` loop. if you getting size how much images you want save on SD card then,

```
for(int n=1 ; n <= size ; n++){
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
 // you other stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: i replace this : Random generator = new Random();
     int n = 10000;
     n = generator.nextInt(n);
     String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";  with your code :for(int n=1 ; n <= size ; n++){
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".png";
but it doesnt save image to sd folder

Comment: @androidqq6: put your code snippet of storing images on sd card from app to understand a solve your problem.

Comment: @androidqq6 : are you creating bitmap before saving an image like this, Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher); please refer below link for more details  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558053/save-image-to-sdcard-from-drawble-resource-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Forgive Random, if you want images in sequential order (as Pragnani suggested and you approved on comments above) and supposing that your code is ok, do this:

```
    Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File imagesFolder = new File(root + "/imagesFolder");    
        imagesFolder.mkdirs();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
            String fname = "Image-" + i + ".png";
            File file = new File (imagesFolder, fname);

            if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

               bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
               out.flush();
               out.close();
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Test it and let me know.

Comment: i tried this before , when press save button once atime , it save 10 images in the same time Sequentially as image-1,image-10, image-2,image-3 and so on

Comment: my friend, my above code is part of full project,to be clear i will update the post with full class include pictures to be saved , it's better to understand