# html tag <div> in string webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I have activity consist of **long textview** must be separated as multiple paragraphs by horizontal colored line (divider) , i used webview to allow adding of:

```
 <div html tag
```

i found after googling that this piece of code forming a **colored horizontal line divider** , but when i applied it to web view it doesont work as below:

```
<div class="aligncenter" style="width:400px;height:0;border-top:2px solid #FF7500;font-size:0;"></div>
```

i applied as below to webview but it doesnt work :

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    String customHtml = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>This is example  " +
                        "<strong>HTML </strong>tag in webviw .&nbsp;</p>" +   
                        "<div class="aligncenter" style="width:400px;height:0;
                           border-top:2px solid #FF7500;font-size:0;"></div>" ;

           webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");}
```

also try it as follow not working :

```
    String customHtml = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>This is example  " +
                        "<strong>HTML </strong>tag in webviw .&nbsp;</p>" +   
                        "<div class=aligncenter style=width:400px;height:0;border-
                         top:2px solid #FF7500;font-size:0;></div>" ;

           webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");}
                                              }
```

Any advice how to adding of div html tag in webview will be appreciated , thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using param = 'value' instead of param = "value" inside the string.

Like this:

```
String customHtml = "<body><h1>Heading Text</h1><p>This is example  " +
                        "<strong>HTML </strong>tag in webviw .&nbsp;</p>" +   
                        "<div class='aligncenter' style='width:400px;height:0;
                           border-top:2px solid #FF7500;font-size:0;'></div>" ;
```

Btw do u have somewhere in **css** set the **aligncenter** class?

Comment: my dear friend im new to android development my goal to have this long textview in paragraphs with colored divider in between also to customize the text in each paragraph like add custom font for each paragraph , different colored text which mean get ability to fully customization of my text view , i searched net alot and looking for example regard html and css creation in assets folder but i cant successfully created then call it from my class , if you help me really i will appreciate your efforts

Comment: @androidqq6 Uhm, so it didn't worked even the way I wrote? I'm not android developing yet, but I want to soon and I've been dealing with html+css several years so I would like to try to help you. 
It would help if u told us if the whole html part doesn't show up or only the divider isn't there.

Comment: ITS WORK BUT 'aligncenter' NOT WORK

Comment: NOW i have the line but other customization i cant get it , really thanks , but if you can help me with other staff i will appreciated , thanks

Comment: Well if u dont have any class with name aligncenter in your CSS file it shouldn't so if u want it to be aligned to center try putting it inside your style='text-align:center;...the other stuff...' OR somtimes u need to put another div around it so the stuff(in this case your line) inside the div would align to center.

Comment: PLEASE  how i can customize my text with html tags and css ,thanks

Comment: @androidqq6 If u haven't worked with html/css yet I suggest going trough some tutorials. It's nothing hard to use tags and to format the text using css. Try this f.e.: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner and http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner
If u want to edit each pargraph - <p> just make a css file with some settings for the paragraph, f.e.: p{font-size: 15pt; color:blue;} I'm not sure how is it with external css in androidapps. Might be better for u to use style='formatting' for each html part u want to customize. Like <p style='color:pink;'>text</p> am I helping anyhow? :x