# Share links to some photos via ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I'm try to share photo from Internet via ACTION_SEND

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri
            .parse("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/PNG_transparency_demonstration_2.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_2.png");

    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "MotivateMe");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
            "share with: "));
```

But this doesn't works, all can't load picture.
It's possible to share photos via internet references or not

Comment: first Save The Photo In Mobile Sdcard and Share

Comment: First Save Image in sdCard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396243/how-to-save-the-image-to-sd-card-on-button-click-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088890/to-save-the-image-in-sdcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your photo reference link will be treated as link. You have to save locally before sharing. Temporary download and then try to send using local link.